# How to embed images in HTML mail for Gamil with dbmail (SQLServer) stored procedure

Tags: html, sql-server, email, base64, sp-send-dbmail

First of all, I want to start what I want and whats my issue, and to clarify that I'm using dbmail (SQLServer) for the sending process, and the main issue is that I don´t get it to work with Gmail.

I need to send mails with integrated images (embedded or attached is the only possibility), but I can't seem to be able to achieve this without linking the images into a dedicated image hosting server.

I've tried embedding with base64 but images sometimes get a length of 6000 characters, and when the stored procedure that I've created gets executed the mail arrives empty and when I check the table sysmail_faileditems they body column appears with an empty value so I guess that the mail gets truncated because of the length of the base64 image.

And when I send the email with the image attached and reference it in src field it never loads where it's supposed to, it just shows as an attachment. This is maybe because of the security policies of Gmail, but in Outlook for desktop works just fine with this setup.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit #1:** In response to @AlwaysLearning, I will proced to show how I implemented the mentioned methods.

## 1 Attachment method:

SQL Code:

```
 @file_attachments  = 'C:\images\image.jpg'
```

HTML Code:

```
 <img src="image.jpg" />
```

## 2 Base64 method:

SQL Code:

```
--in this method, I store the image in a base64 as a varchar(MAX)  
--in a table and replace it in the stored procedure in execution time.

Set @emailbody = Replace(@emailbody,'^^IMAGE^^' ,@imagebase64)
```

HTML Code:

```
<img alt="image" width=200 height=86 src="^^IMAGE^^"/>
```

*The real issue* is that both these methods actually work with some email clients, but not with gmail, so obviously I'm missing some specifics or it's impossible to do it this way.

Comment: Show us what SQL you've tried. The most difficult part of embedded images is setting up a multipart/related message to contain your HTML message body and the related images, each with their own Content-ID headers. This isn't new, though, RFC 2387 has been around since 1998.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning , I have added examples of what I've tried.